# How to render a paragraph as a function inside a react component?

Tags: reactjs, components

I am trying to build up an article using react's Fragment for paragraphs, the function works fine in rendering the multi-line text with spaces and for some reason it is not rendering on the Article app. What am I doing wrong ? here is the file with all functions on it, so there is no need to export external sources:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const covidText = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim. Integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra.

Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Orci ac auctor augue mauris. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a.

Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in. Quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum.

Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu`

const paragraph = () =>
  covidText.split("\n").map((text, index) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={index}>
        {text}
        <br />
      </Fragment>
    );
  });

const Article = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
    <p>{paragraph}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Article />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Did you open the console and read messages? `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.` You have to add `()` after paragraph like `<p>{paragraph()}</p>`

Comment: Looks like you just want `paragraph` to be a component. Rename it to `Paragraph` and use it like this: `<Paragraph>`.